# How do I fix this ruby template to fix formatting of resulting file?

Tags: ruby, puppet

I'm trying to write a file on my system using puppet here's the declaration:

```
file { '/etc/salt/grains':
  ensure  => present,
  content => template('pp_salt_manager/grains.erb'),
}
```

And this is my really short .erb file:

```
<% @machine_info.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= "#{key}: #{value}" %>
<% end %>
```

For reference, this is machine_info:

```
$machine_info = {'deployment' => 'c7', 'local' => 'US', 'env' => 'stable'}
```

My problem is, this is the output file:

```
_ # Empty line
  deployment: c7
_ # Another empty line
  local: US
_ # Once again, an empty line
  env: stable
```

How do I make it look like this:

```
deployment: c7
local: US
env: stable
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try it with css turned off in your browser.

Comment: This isn't ruby on rails. I'm not viewing it in a browser. This is a template for a file in puppet. I'll edit the post to be more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a "-%>" instead of "%>" to close might help:

```
<% @machine_info.each do |key, value| -%>
  <%= "#{key}: #{value}" %>
<% end -%>
```

Here's a link to the puppet docs:
https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html#trim-mode